# Modifying category_name arg with a checkbox form Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, filter

I want to build an explore page template on my Wordpress website where a user can visit the page and by default, posts in all categories will be shown (This I can do). I would like to add a form with checkboxes at the top of the page where the user can narrow down their search. The user should be able to select multiple categories and once they click submit the query will update to show only posts in those categories. Below, I will post the two pieces of code I have at this moment.

This code creates the form that displays the inputs and holds the category_name value. Right now, it sends the user to the category page upon submit and that's not what I need it to do.

```
$zones = get_field('zones_list');
$business_types = get_field('business_type');

    echo'<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="'.home_url('/').'">
        <div>';
        foreach( $zones as $zone ):
            echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$zone->slug.'" name="category_name">'.$zone->name.'</input>';
        endforeach;
        echo'</div>
        <div>';
        foreach( $business_types as $business_type ):
            echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$business_type->slug.'" name="category_name">'.$business_type->name.'</input>';
        endforeach;
        echo'</div>
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>';
```

This code holds the args for the loop i'm creating on the page.

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'category_name' => '',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'=> '3',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); global $post;
```

I now that if I manually add multiple category names in the category_name field like this

```
'category_name' => 'zone1,zone2',
```

The query displays only posts in those categories. Which is what I need it to do, but I need the user to be able to select the categories they would like to see via a form on the front-end.

Is there a way to create a form on the front-end of my website that can update the "category_name" section when a user selects the checkboxes and clicks submit?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution. I'm not sure it's the correct way to do it, but it works.

This is the updated code

```
$zones = get_field('zones_list');
$business_types = get_field('business_type');

echo'<form role="search" method="post" id="searchform">
    <div>';
    foreach( $zones as $zone ):
        echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$zone->slug.'" name="category_name[]">'.$zone->name.'</input>';
    endforeach;
    echo'</div>
    <div>';
    foreach( $business_types as $business_type ):
        echo'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$business_type->slug.'" name="category_name[]">'.$business_type->name.'</input>';
    endforeach;
    echo'</div>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['category_name'])) {
    $cat_name = $_POST['category_name'];
    $cat_formated = implode('+', $cat_name);
}


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'category_name' => $cat_formated ,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'=> '3',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
);
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); global $post;
```

Comment: you can use wp_update_term

Comment: How would I send that information from the form? @JoshuaBelarmino

Comment: if you are goin to use checkbox.. then make sure that the name attribute is something like name="something[]" so you can iterate in the in the backend..